# ServerSelectionTimeoutError al insertar documents in DocumentDB

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-s3

Tengo un bucket S3 con

- json de perfumes de una marca o
- carpetas de una marca con perfumes en formato json.

Sé cómo obtener su índice, pero me gustaría insertar estos objetos en mi base de datos documentdb, en colecciones correspondientes a su marca.

¿Saben cómo puedo hacer eso?

Hasta hoy intenté:

```
import boto3
import pymongo
import sys


def iterate_bucket_items(bucket):
    """
    Generator that iterates over all objects in a given s3 bucket

    See http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2 
    for return data format
    :param bucket: name of s3 bucket
    :return: dict of metadata for an object
    """


    client = boto3.client('s3')
    paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket)

    for page in page_iterator:
        if page['KeyCount'] > 0:
            for item in page['Contents']:
                yield item


##Create a MongoDB client, open a connection to Amazon DocumentDB as a replica set and specify the read preference as secondary preferred
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://user:paswword@datahub.cluster-1.eu-west-3.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false') 

##Specify the database to be used
db = client.perfumes
c = 0
for i in iterate_bucket_items(bucket='datahubpredicity'):
    pathname = i['Key']
    if pathname.contains('/'):
        collection = pathname.split[0]
        # col = db[collection]
        # col.insert_one(i)
    c+=1
    if c >= 10:
        break
    # ##Specify the collection to be used
    # col = db.sample_collection
    
    # ##Insert a single document
    # col.insert_one(i)
    
    # ##Print the result to the screen
    # print(x)
    
##Close the connection
client.close()
```

Pero devuelve:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 
datahub.cluster-1.eu-west-3.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017: 
timed out, Timeout: 30s, 
Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6254472217824b192df5665d, 
                      topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, 
                      servers: [<ServerDescription ('datahub.cluster-1.eu-west-3.docdb.amazonaws.com', 27017) server_type: Unknown, 
                      rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('datahub.cluster-1.eu-west-3.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017: timed out')>]>
```

Comment: Cambia el URI de conexión, si es una instancia AWS entonces esto: `mongodb://user:paswword ...` debería ser: `mongodb+srv://user:paswword ...`. Prueba eso y comenta el resultado.

Comment: Otro detalle, en tu cadena de conexión veo: `replicaSet=rs0`, ¿tu Replica Set se llama así?